# iOS - navigation bar left/right margin issue

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

[image: Picture 1]

Can anyone guess why there is padding in navigation bar from left and right?

I can't figure what caused padding. Have I misplaced some property ? 
Any guesses?

Comment: Can you show your storyboard?

Comment: @Birendra its a default back button

Comment: @Amanpreet : padding is on iPhone 6 , iPhone 5s is good .

Comment: Do you mean on Storyboard its OK?

Comment: problem in when running on a device .

iPhone 5s is okay but in iPhone 6 it's not good there is padding

Comment: Are you giving padding etc to navigation bar? Because usually we cant see such a issues.

Comment: @Amanpreet no nothing like that

Comment: you can use custom bar button

Comment: Try with new Navigation controller.

Comment: Have you added Navigationbar or using Created by UINavigationController? and show your storyboard/xib.